# Problem with configuration java security provider by java.security file for EAP 7.2 and OpenJDK11

Tags: java, jboss-eap-7, hsm, openjdk-11

I’m try to deploy war app on Eap7.2 with OpenJDK 11 (Zulu) and I'm having problem with java.security file.
My app need Luna Provider (for HSM).
Of course, I added a line

„security.provider.14=com.safenetinc.luna.provider.LunaProvider”

in
..\zulu-11\conf\security\java.security

But when i start server and display all security providers i don't see the new LunaProvider. To display all providers i use this code.

```
for (Provider provider: Security.getProviders()) {
    System.out.println(provider.getName()); 
}
```

In simple test with one class out of EAP (running from command line) i see Luna Provider, but not with Eap7.2.
I also notes that EAP application see more providers than declared on java.security file and it seems that Eap 7.2 using different security configuration.

How to configure java.security-LunaProvider for EAP 7.2?

Comment: Did you check whether EAP already has its own java.security file that overrides the default one?

Comment: Yes, I have nowhere found Eap to have its own java.security file defined or something similar. There is no such file in the EAP directory structure itself.

Comment: You can still set a provider programmatically through `Security.addProvider()`. This should be working even in case EAP does some magic upfront.